# Hide parts of menu in Angular (permission)

Tags: angular, authentication, angular-material

i am building a Dashboard using Angular. The users of the dashboard are 1: Administrator (who is allowed to see the complete menu in sidebar) and 2: employee (who are only allowed to see part of that menu in the sidebar).

How should i define the menu items, so that they can be displayed dynamically based of the defined user permissions?

Thanks

Comment:  can you share some of your code ?

Comment: The first thing that came to mind is AuthGuards (see https://angular.io/guide/router#the-sample-application)

Comment: If you have roles on your users, you can hide/show content that is relevant to the permission level.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { PermissionService } from '../services/web-api/permission.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAuthorizeAction]'
})
export class AuthorizeActionDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input('path') path: string;
  @Input('permission') permission: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private permissionService: PermissionService) {
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    const authResult = this.permissionService.isAuthorized(this.path, this.permission);
    if (authResult !== true) {
      this.el.nativeElement.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

You can use the following and implement on any item:
Example usage:

```
<button mat-button appAuthorizeAction [path]="'ADMIN_PANEL'" [permission]="'EXECUTE'">Click me!</button>
```

In case the user is authorized to perform the execute action, it will keep the button, else it will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet from my role-guard:

```
public canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> {
    const roles: UserRoles[] = route.data['roles'];
    return this.authenticationService.currentPrincipal.pipe(take(1), map((user) => {
        // console.log(roles);
        return roles.every((val) => user.roles.includes(val));
    }));
}
```

So you can see that my user authentication gets and sets the currentUser's roles.

When a user is created, their `Principle` roles are set as to what type of user they are. (they could be updated by admin)

Let me know if you need more.